# Hibernate @ManyToOne "Target Entity is not defined"

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have two entities, and when i use @ManyToOne annotation, i'm getting an error saying `"Target Entity is not defined"`.

I'm just following a tutorial and i can't seem to find what i did wrong.

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name="BEO_TABLE")
        public class BeoBean {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue
            @Column(name="Beo_Id")
            private int beoId;

    //other variables


            @OneToMany(mappedBy="beo")
            private List<EventsBean> listOfEvents = new ArrayList<EventsBean>();

    //getters and setters
}
```

**AND**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EVENTS_TABLE")
public class EventsBean {

    //other variables

    @ManyToOne //error here
    @JoinColumn(name="Beo_Id")
    private BeoBean beo;

//getters and setters
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does EVENTS_TABLE has Beo_Id column?

Comment: yes it does, funny thing is, the error disappears whenever i clean the project. but comes back again after a while.

Comment: Do you get the error in Eclipse?

Comment: yes. the program runs fine. But it has a red mark which is kinda annoying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error has nothing to do with your application. It works fine but the error is in **Eclipse**.

To remove this (and other JPA) error message simply disable the JPA validation under `Window -> Preferences -> Validation` and here remove the checks from `JPA Validator`.

Generally most applications can be developed without any validators because bigger projects' validation slows down compiling in eclipse way too much. In this case click `Disable all` in the same window below the table of validators.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your persistence unit in eclipse. Add BeoBean  to the PU. You should be sorted

Answer (score 1):

225/5000
I often had this kind of false error in Eclipse, and it is solved by cleaning the project.

Select the project, then click the Project / Clean ... menu and then Clean button

Worked for me once again.

JJMB